# Passing arguments to @selector method

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, selector

I have added a `UIButton` in a table view. Now when I click a particular button, I need to get the details of the object corresponding to that row.

```
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(invite:contactmail:) 
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I have used this method for the button; how can I pass arguments to this selector method? Or is there any other way to pass arguments to this method when this button is clicked?

Comment: use the `UIButton`'s `tag` value for posting identifier about the row, and inside the action handler method you can read back that `tag` value for further, you don't need to post anything else, because you are already on the _controller-layer_, and you have access to _model-layer_ and all data as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

methods you add as actions to a UIControl can have 3 different signatures

```
- (void)action
- (void)action:(id)sender
- (void)action:(id)sender event:(UIEvent *)event
```

you can't pass your own object. Often it is possible to get whatever object you are trying to pass with the help of the sender (your button) object.

If you have a button in a tableviewcell you could use something like this to get the indexpath of the cell.

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    CGPoint buttonOriginInTableView = [button convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonOriginInTableView];

    // do something
}
```

and with the indexPath you can get the object you need.

Answer (score 0):

No not really. The click event is

```
-(IBAction) fnc:(id)sender;
```

If you want to call another method you will need to do so in a function of that form.

```
-(IBAction) fnc:(id) sender
{
   UIButton *b = (UIButton*) sender;
   [self otherFnc:b arg:arg1 arg2:arg2];
}
```