# Pass string as tag or other value in button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I need to pass string data with button, like tag, how can I do so?

```
[button setTag:tg];
```

tg is nsstring. Maybe use other property and not tag?

Comment: Is the button in a tableview? Then look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246768/passing-arguments-to-selector-method/5246835#5246835)

Comment: Can you please mention the scenario, why you want to add string value to tag property? I guess better way would be I pass my value on particular event method like UITouchUpInside. Please provide more description in question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Associated Objects`

```
@interface UIButton (Tagged)

 @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *tag;

@end
```

---

```
#import <objc/runtime.h> 

static const void *tagKey = &tagKey;

@implementation UIButton (Tagged)

- (void)setTag:(NSSting *)tag
{
   objc_setAssociatedObject(self, tagKey, tag, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC);
}

- (NSString *)tag
{
  return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, tagKey);
}
@end
```

Get reference [associated-objects](http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/) and [link](http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/adding-properties-category-using-associated-objects.html)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set `NSString` variable to integer property, it is not possible in Objective-C (if it was an object, technically you could, but you are dealing with a primitive here).

**You could use associated properties in Objective-C runtime. You can set any additional variable to any object using this API and then also retrieve it at a later point. See the link below for more information.**

http://oleb.net/blog/2011/05/faking-ivars-in-objc-categories-with-associative-references/

Method `objc_setAssociatedObject` is the one you are looking for.